# How do I turn off the calendar popup widget on the date field?

Tags: webforms

noob here,

I have a form that requests a birthdate. I have set that field type to a date field.

When on a desktop, the user can either enter the date directly into the field--this is great--or use the calendar widget.

Here is my challenge:

When filling the form in by phone, the calendar widget pops up and forces the user to use the calendar to enter the birthdate, this is a pain as you cannot select a year then date--in other words, the user is forced to scroll by month back to the year they are born.

Is there a way to turn the calendar widget off?

Comment: Which phone models?

Comment: Google Pixel, Samsung, Iphone